# mysql - Displaying unwanted repeat results in one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-many, relationship

I have 3 tables.

First is a Company Table: `Company_ID, Company_name` etc

2nd is a Jobs Table: `JOB_ID, Job_Name, Job_description` etc

3rd is a Comp_Jobs table: `Comp_Job_ID, Company_ID, Job_ID`

I am trying to run a query to create a join with these tables so that it will display all the jobs assoicated with a company. eg ive got 2 jobs for company 1 i want to display. but when i run this query:

```
Select Company.Company_name, Jobs.Job_ID, Company.CAddress, 
Jobs.Job_Name, Jobs.Job_Description from Company, jobs
join company_job where Company.Company_ID = Company_Job.Company_ID
order by Company_job.Job_ID;
```

it would repeat the result, as in company 1 will display jobs 1 and 2 twice.

any tekkers?

Comment: You could use `GROUP BY` on the job name

Comment: tried your group by, but in the jobs table there will be abit of data redundancy due to the likes of a 'repair' being a different price for a different company. but thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Company.Company_name, Jobs.Job_ID, Company.CAddress, 
Jobs.Job_Name, Jobs.Job_Description
from Company
join company_job on Company.Company_ID = Company_Job.Company_ID
join jobs on jobs.Job_ID =  Company_Job.job_id
order by Company_job.Job_ID;
```

Try this. Not sure if this is what you asked for 

 There was no proper join condition with Company and jobs

Comment: yes thats the ticket there, thanks. didnt think there would have to be two joins, suppose makes sense when think about it

Comment: @Andrew - NOTE, that your original query also has two joins. the comma is like JOIN if you don't specify a JOIN condition

Comment: @luksch where do you mean when you mention the comma just so i know for the future to look out for it. do you mean when i was doing the "from company, jobs"?

Comment: yes exactly. have a look here for a discussion of the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Answer (score 1):

You should use `INNER JOIN` to only display the rows you want:

```
SELECT Company.Company_name, Jobs.Job_ID, 
       Company.CAddress, Jobs.Job_Name, Jobs.Job_Description
FROM Comp_Jobs
INNER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.Job_ID = Comp_Jobs.Job_ID
INNER JOIN Company ON Company.Company_ID = Comp_Jobs.Company_ID    
ORDER BY Company_job.Job_ID;
```